# insert hyphen in a 9 digit number after 5 digits using regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have to automatically insert a hyphen in 9 digit number on text change event in c# only not javascript.

So if my number is 123456789 then it automatically  becomes 12345-6789.

I would like to use regex.match.

My try:

The regex "^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$" is how the result should be.

so,

```
Regex regTest = new Regex("^\\d{5}(-\\d{4})?$");

Match match = regTest.Match(s);

if (match.Success)
           {
              var numString = match.Value;
           }
```

But the above does not returns a success.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Why does it have to be a RegEx? You can use normal string methods to achieve this.

Comment: I would use the simple [String.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.insert(v=VS.71).aspx) for this problem, not a regex.

Comment: You are trying to kill a fly with the DeathStar

Comment: What does inserting a hyphen have to do with regular expressions?

Answer (score 6):

Your code sample simply *checks* that the format is `xxxxx-xxxx`. It doesn't insert the hyphen.

You do not need a RexEx to insert a hyphen:

```
myString.Insert(5, "-");
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression seems correct. You can verify it here:
http://derekslager.com/blog/posts/2007/09/a-better-dotnet-regular-expression-tester.ashx

Most probably you are not inserting the '-' and then matching.